# Why does the sun appear 13x bigger through diffraction in Voyager 1 image from 1990, but not from Earth?

Tags: star, optics

The sun in the Voyager 1 photo here from 1990 appears 13x bigger than its diameter, diffraction of course. On Earth, photographs of the sun do not make it appear 13x bigger. Why?

A description of the photo from [jpl.nasa.gov](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA00450),

> "The wide-angle was taken with the camera's darkest filter (a methane
>   absorption band), and the shortest possible exposure (5 thousandths of
>   a second) to avoid saturating the camera's vidicon tube with scattered
>   sunlight. "

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the value "13" times bigger from?  Why do you say "diffraction of course"

Comment: distance to Venus, 77 solar diameters, see position of planets and Voyager 1 here,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot#/media/File:Voyager_1_-_14_February_1990.png

Comment: Can you show your working?

Comment: its known data, the distance to Venus from the sun is on average 77 solar diameters, Venus is in the composite closest to the sun, and Earth the box next to it

Comment: Apparently the Sun also has 8 spikes coming out of it and an off-centre corona with 2 distinct zones with different brightness.

Comment: yes sure, glare rays and lens flares

Comment: the hypothesis that the suns corona, which is luminous as you see in a solar eclipse for example, appears from distance with surrounding space adding contrast as luminous, does not reject optics in any way

Comment: Along the ecliptic there are dust particles that orbit the sun on the ecliptic plane just like every planet in our solar system does. These reflect light, and can be seen for example with the "zodiacal lights". As you know, light pollution makes luminous objects less visible in contrast to the surrounding space, that is why you cannot see the stars as well in cities, or during day time. The Voyager 1 was 32 degrees above the plane of the ecliptic.

Answer (score 5):

Don't base the size of the Sun on what you see in that image because the Sun is over-exposed.  The big spot in the center of the diffraction spikes are saturated pixels because they all appear to have the same value (the spot looks uniform) so you don't know what their real values are; you would need to take a shorter-exposure image (or put filters in front of the lens) if you wanted to take a proper picture of the Sun.  Since Venus is a lot dimmer than the Sun, they set the exposure long enough to see it and accepted the fact that the Sun would be over-exposed.  You see the same thing in [some of the Hubble images](http://hubblesite.org/image/4229/gallery) where to bring out the background stars, the brighter ones are over-exposed.

Another way of looking at it, if you see an image where you can very clearly see the diffraction spikes, that part of the image is over-exposed.

Comment: the image where Venus is visible was a separate photo, it is composited into the photograph, same with the image of Earth

Comment: Either way, you can't resolve the Sun in that picture because it is washed out.  For instance, look at [these streetlight](https://mediaindia.eu/freestyle/india-witnesses-worlds-largest-street-light-replacement-programme/) images.  Clearly the streetlights aren't as physically large as the images suggest they are.

Comment: what do you mean either way, the images are composited. there is no either way, there is one way since the image is what it is. most images of the sun, if you Google, are not 13x larger, they're less than 2x larger, why would the Voyager 1 image capture it as 13x larger, if it was making a composite why overexpose the image for the sun?

Comment: By either way, I meant that it doesn't matter whether it was a composite image or not because the image of the Sun is overexposed just like the image of some of the stars in the Hubble image are, and the images of the streetlamp are.  I don't know the source of the image so I can't tell you what the Voyager image team was trying to look, but I would be surprised if they were trying to image the Sun.  Does the image not look overexposed to you?  [Here is another example](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/sites/www.cfa.harvard.edu/files/images/pr/2014-23/1/base.jpg) of overexposed stars.

Comment: The composite is of the sun, earth and venus, would guess it was planned, the planets were in nice positions, and have been photographed one by one,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot#/media/File:Voyager_1_-_14_February_1990.png

Comment: isn't the most likely possibility that they were imaging the sun ("trying to image the sun"), and also imaged the planets with higher exposure, and then combined the images into a composite?

here is from jpl,
"The wide-angle was taken with the camera's darkest filter (a methane absorption band), and the shortest possible exposure (5 thousandths of a second) to avoid saturating the camera's vidicon tube with scattered sunlight. "
https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA00450

Comment: so the exposure time of the image the sun is in was 0.005s, and the one of earth and venus 0.5

Comment: From what you said, it seems they were trying to get the "family picture", which in itself is really cool.  But also from what you said, they used their darkest filter and their shortest exposure, so they did all they could do for the Sun.  Even with those settings the Sun was just too bright (but not so bright as to wash out the whole picture).  Voyager wasn't meant to image the Sun.  If it was, they would have included an appropriate filter, like an [H-$\alpha$ filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-alpha).  Check out [SOHO](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov) for a mission designed for that.

Comment: are there, like the street lights you used as an example, any other images of the sun at 0.005s exposure that show it 13x larger than it is?

Comment: I was thinking, and that may sound absurd, that at that distance, 40 AU, the furthest photo ever taken of the sun, the suns corona was visible as a luminescent disk, for whatever reasons. The corona is 13x the suns diameter, and if you measure the disc in that image, it's 13x the suns diameter.